# ASP.NET How to add datetime as default value to data source details view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, detailsview

I want to add the current date time as default value in the following field as default value.

I tired the following

```
<asp:Parameter Name="AddedDate" Type="DateTime" DefaultValue="<% DateTime.Now.ToString() %>"/>
```

and

```
<asp:Parameter Name="AddedDate" Type="DateTime" DefaultValue="<% Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString()) %>"/>
```

But got error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How do i fix it? and is there any better approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a Default the way you are doing, but you can pass the `DateTime.Now` as parameter in the DetailsView `Inserting/Updating` event. e.g.

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
  e.Values["AddedDate"] = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: thanks. i am using for insert. but if i add your code to mine, i get error. the code is :    protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        e.NewValues["AddedDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

Comment: looks like insertevent doesn't have NewValues attrivute. Error is: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'NewValues' and no extension method 'NewValues' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: for inserting, it shoulu e.Values, I have just updated my answer try now.

Comment: weird. now getting this error: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. Not sure what it is the cause